# Getting 'Runtime error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error' while trying to assign formula to a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the "Runtime error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error" when I try to execute the following code, and I have no idea why this is happening.

```
Dim rangeOfReg As Range
Dim rowOfRegStringfied As String
rowOfRegStringfied = LTrim(Str(rowOfReg))
Set rangeOfReg = Worksheets("Sheet").Range(colOfReg + rowOfRegStringfied)
rangeOfReg.Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(H2:J" + rowOfRegStringfied + ";'Seg a quarta';J2:J" + rowOfRegStringfied + ")"
```

The value of colOfReg, when it is read is "H", the value of rowOfReg is 20. The error is thrown when this last line is executed.

I have tried not assigning that Range to that variable of type range, but instead calling "Worksheets("Sheet").Range(colOfReg + rowOfRegStringfied)" in the next line but didn't work.
I have also tried replacing commas in the formula being assigned, but the error is still there.

Comment: `.Formula` expects US-EN.  That requires `,` rather than `;` and `"` for string constants (will need to be delimited).  Or consider using `.FormulaLocal`

Comment: Strings should be concatenated using '&' not '+'.  Also, for debugging purposes it is a good strategy to assemble your string in a variable first, so that you can see the final string. e.g. dim myF as string: myf="=AVERAGEIF(H2:J" & rowOfRegStringfied & ";'Seg a quarta';J2:J" &  rowOfRegStringfied & ")".  Then subsequently 'rangeOfReg.Formula = myF'

Comment: Thanks you very much for the help. But how can I delimit Seg a quarta with double quotes(") seems like this is why i am still getting the error.

Comment: ";" & chr$(34) & "Seg a quarta" & chr%(34) &";J2J:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the corrections suggested by @chrisneilsen and @freeflow (all are needed), your issue comes down to this piece of the string:

```
",'Seg a quarta',J2:J"
```

As you noted, that requires double quotes for

```
"Seg a quarta"
```

Inserting a double quote inside a string requires "escaping" it so Excel doesn't interpret it as the end of the string. In VBA, use two double quotes together to escape the double quote:

```
",""Seg a quarta"",J2:J"
```

So the full statement will be:

```
rangeOfReg.Formula = "=AVERAGEIF(H2:J" & rowOfRegStringfied & ",""Seg a quarta"",J2:J" & rowOfRegStringfied & ")"
```

Excel accepts that without complaining.